# Cropping texture2d on all sides in xna c#

Tags: c#, xna, crop, texture2d

i am trying to crop a texture2d in xna. i have found the following code which will crop the image on the top and right sides, i have played around with the code and cannot figure a way to crop all sides at a specific interval. below is the code i have been trying to modify:

any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

```
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0, 0, 580, 480);

        Texture2D cropped = new Texture2D(heightMap1.GraphicsDevice, area.Width, area.Height);
        Color[] data = new Color[heightMap1.Width * heightMap1.Height];
        Color[] cropData = new Color[cropped.Width * cropped.Height];

        heightMap1.GetData(data);

        int index = 0;


        for (int y = 0; y < area.Y + area.Height; y++) // for each row
        {

                for (int x = 0; x < area.X + area.Width; x++) // for each column 
                {
                    cropData[index] = data[x + (y * heightMap1.Width)];
                    index++;
                }

        }

    cropped.SetData(cropData);
```

Comment: Whats wrong with it? What is causing trouble?

Comment: i need to crop 20 pixels off all sides of the image, this will only crop 20 off the top and right side :(

Comment: Do you need to crop the texture and provide the output back to the user as some type of download or do you have to draw the texture cropped?  If you are attempting to draw some portion of a larger texture to the screen then that affects

Comment: i dont need to provide this to the user but later on in the program it is used just as a texture, is there a way of cropping it and putting it back as a tecture2d?

Comment: well basically the program is capturing depth frames from the xbox kinect and saving them in a texture. i would like to crop the all sides of the images to remove over spread from the kinect as its position cannot be moved, cheers for the quick reply guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to crop a texture. Note that the `GetData` method can already select rectangular subsection of the image - there is no need to manually crop.

```
// Get your texture
Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myTexture");

// Calculate the cropped boundary
Rectangle newBounds = texture.Bounds;
const int resizeBy = 20;
newBounds.X += resizeBy;
newBounds.Y += resizeBy;
newBounds.Width -= resizeBy * 2;
newBounds.Height -= resizeBy * 2;

// Create a new texture of the desired size
Texture2D croppedTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, newBounds.Width, newBounds.Height);

// Copy the data from the cropped region into a buffer, then into the new texture
Color[] data = new Color[newBounds.Width * newBounds.Height];
texture.GetData(0, newBounds, data, 0, newBounds.Width * newBounds.Height);
croppedTexture.SetData(data);
```

Of course, keep in mind that `SpriteBatch.Draw` can take a `sourceRectangle` parameter, so you may not even need to copy the texture data around at all! Just use a subsection of the original texture. For example:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, newBounds, Color.White);
```

(Where `newBounds` is calculated in the same way as in the first code listing.)